# How to use Twitter Streaming API wih PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json, twitter

I was successfully able to retrieve my user timeline for display on my website using

```
$tweets = simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/" . $userID . ".rss");
```

for quite some time. However, having had more and more page views lately, I am finding now that I am getting the dreaded `HTTP 400` error due to rate limiting.

I have been trying to get my head around the Twitter streaming API with litte/no luck (I have no experience with OAuth/JSON so it's completely alien to me).

I've looked at the code for [TwitStream](http://iamnoahcooper.com/TwitStream/) which provides access to the Search API using AJAX/JQuery. Unfortunately, I don't post enough to provide consistent search results so this is not an option.

I haven't found the documentation from Twitter very useful (I'm sure it is if JSON etc isn't very new to you) and I haven't found any simple end-to-end examples of using the Streaming API to fetch the last `x` posts from a user (i.e. me) from a PHP webpage. There are plenty of examples using command line utilities (e.g. `curl`) to open a stream but this may not be possible on some webservers (I may not have command line access).

I would be massively grateful if someone could provide me with code for a simple PHP/AJAX/JQuery but NOT Ruby/Python webpage that fetches the last 10 tweets from a users timeline. I don't care if it polls or anything for the time being, just a simple fetch of the tweets on the page load would be great!

So to clarify, I am after a simple example (e.g. don't bother with CSS/making the JSON response human readable etc) similar to to [TwitStream](http://iamnoahcooper.com/TwitStream/) but for fetching user timelines and displaying them on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
`<?php
$username = "TwitterUsername"; // Your twitter username.
$limit = "5"; // Number of tweets to pull in.

/* These prefixes and suffixes will display before and after the entire block of tweets. */
$prefix = ""; // Prefix - some text you want displayed before all your tweets.
$suffix = ""; // Suffix - some text you want displayed after all your tweets.
$tweetprefix = ""; // Tweet Prefix - some text you want displayed before each tweet.
$tweetsuffix = "<br>"; // Tweet Suffix - some text you want displayed after each tweet.

$feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=" . $limit;

function parse_feed($feed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix) {

$feed = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $feed);
$feed = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $feed);
$clean = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);

$amount = count($clean) - 1;

echo $prefix;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
$cleaner = explode("</content>", $clean[$i]);
echo $tweetprefix;
echo $cleaner[0];
echo $tweetsuffix;
}

echo $suffix;
}

$twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);
parse_feed($twitterFeed, $prefix, $tweetprefix, $tweetsuffix, $suffix);
?>`
```

I found this at: http://www.instantshift.com/2009/05/25/10-twitter-hacks-for-your-wordpress-blog/

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems fairly similar to what I was using before. I was under the assumption I was to use the Streaming API eg. `stream.twitter.com` to avoid the rate limiting problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this class
https://github.com/KartikTalwar/Twitter-Class

Comes with excellent simple examples and you can display tonnes of details with just a couple of lines of code

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately this also seems to use the first method I described above which is subject to rate control. I specifically need an example that uses the `Streaming` API.

Comment: @chris do you know what the post parameters are? because if you do you can use the `submitPOST($param, $url)` function from this class and it basically is simply the php version of that command line `curl` https://github.com/KartikTalwar/Scraper-Class

Comment: If I'm reading `https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods` correctly, I believe the post method would be `http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json` and then I could construct `$params` like `$params = count=10`?

Comment: @Chris the `$params` need to be an associative array so you will be creating an array `$params = array("count" => "10", "username" => "blah", "password" => "password");` etc.. you can check out the examples.php file. I believe it has a working example of the post method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get around rate limiting when pulling the tweets from your server without doing one of two things:

1) Pull down the tweets at a time interval and cache them on your site

2) Have users authenticate themselves and using their tokens to pull the tweets

Of course there is a *much* simpler way to do this. Request the timeline in javascript on the page itself. These timeline requests will count against the user's IP that views the page rather than your server.

Here is a site that has some javascript samples for this: http://www.mivamerchant.com/blog/how-to-make-custom-twitter-feed-for-your-website